# 'java -version' command shows different version than what I have

Tags: java

In my `C:\Program files\java` folder I have three folders:

```
jdk1.6.0_45
jre6
jre7
```

However typing the command `java -version` in the command prompt gives the following output:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
```

How does that make sense? I think it should have outputed `jdk1.6.0_45`. How can this be explained?

Comment: Why do you think it should have printed a version corresponding to Java 6?

Comment: The `java` command invokes the Java *interpreter* not the *compiler* so it would be found in a JRE package (i.e. `jre7`).

Comment: @Elliott If I want to compile using JDK7, should I be able to do that?

Comment: @Prog You need to install a JDK7 package (just go download latest version!) and then use the `javac` command to compile. :)

Comment: @Elliott I see. What does it actually mean to compile using JDK X instead of JDK Y? Is it that a program compiled with JDK X will be able to run on JRE X and a program compiled with JDK Y will be able to run on JRE Y?

Comment: @Prog A program compiled with JDK X is more or less guaranteed to run on all JREs with a version number greater than or equal to X.

Comment: @Elliott So that means that there is 1 to 1 correspondence between JDKs and JREs? Compiling using JDK X will mean the program will run on JRE X and later, and compiling using JDK Y will mean the program will run on JRE Y or later? A JDK is simply a compiler for a specific JRE (and it's future versions)?

Comment: @Prog Yep, exactly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered this in the comments thread but for future reference:

Broadly speaking, the JDK package determines the version of the Java compiler (`javac`) you have and the JRE package determines the version of the Java interpreter (`java`) you have.

The version that is run when you type `java` or `javac` in the command line is the version that is listed in your `PATH` environmental variable, which will generally point to the newest version from the newest package (the Java installer does this for you).

The JDK will install the corresponding JRE at the same time so you'll have the same version of `java` and `javac` by just installing the latest JDK.

Comment: After installing a new JDK (and JRE), do I need to 'tell Java' to 'connect' to the new JDK? Or is it enough to just download and install it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it finds have from inside the jre7 folder? You can check your PATH to see where it finds executables.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `jre7` so I assume it is `update 51`

Java takes the newest version by default.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be if and where the JAVA_HOME ENV points to.